# grep in Powershell

Tags: grep, powershell

What is the mos easy/comfortable way to use Powershells built-in functions to emulate `grep` like behaviour?

In scripts I use something like this

```
dir "*.filter" | foreach-object{
    $actfile = $_
    $readerrorfile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
    $found = $false
    $content = Get-Content $actfile 2> $readerrorfile
    $readerror = Get-Content $readerrorfile
    if($readerror -match "Error"){
        echo "Error while reading from file $actfile"
        echo $readerror
        del $readerrorfile
        Write-Host "stopping execution"
        exit
    }else{
        del $readerrorfile
        if($content -match "keyword|regex"){
            echo "found in $actfile"
            $found = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I fairly sure there is an easier/shorter version for that, maybe a one-liner. So, what is the best way to it the `grep` way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I normally do something like:

```
dir *.txt | select-string "keyword|regex"
```

For a matching file, this shows me the name of the file, the line number and the contents of the line. This is also pipeline-friendly. I suggest that you have a look at Select-string by using:

```
help Select-String -Detailed
```

Comment: although this mostly works, if the line is too long the it's wrapped after 120 characters even when piped to file

Comment: You won't have an issue with wrapping if you pipe `Select-String` to `Set-Content` or `Add-Content`

Answer (score 3):

I find this to be a better alternative than piping dir:

> findstr "keyword|regex" *.txt

This doesn't have that wrapping problem.